# Geny Motion - trick to download the .ova files for Ubuntu 12.04 (old links are not working)

Tags: 12.04, virtualbox, android, downloads, ubuntu-for-android

I'm using the Ubuntu 12.04 LTS version .

I had also installed the genymotion.
But I had a slow internet connection, so I'm unable to download that large size file in my home.

I had searched many many blogs,sites too..
Where they are provided the link to download the .ova files, but if we try to download means the 404 error comes.

Where as for some .ova files we can download but majority of the .ova files are not getting.

So I want to get the .ova files and the links and the way to download them in net cafe.

Answer (score 5):

I downloaded all .ova files by selecting download in genymotion but not actually downloading.

1. login in to genymotion in your pc with your **user:pass**
2. click "ADD virtual devices". then select required device.
3. when download starts, just after few kb, you just stop the download.
4. go to log file of genymotion, named something like "genymotion.log"
5. open the file and go to nearly end of log you will find latest .ova file link.

   the link looks like:

   ```
    http://files2.genymotion.com/dists/x.x/ova/genymotion_vbox86p_x.xxxxxxxxxx.ova
   ```
6. you can repeat the above step 2 to 4 if you want to download more than one device files.
7. copy the link(S) and go to net-cafe and download the same.

In Ubuntu the log file is located in "*.Genymobile*" hidden directory in your home directory. And in Windows iy's located in "*%localappdata%\Genymobile*" directory(open via Run dialog <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>).

Comment: Listed http://stackoverflow.com/a/41334582/3678849

Answer (score 0):

I think you should read this. It has a various links to downloading the genymotion ova files you need

A quick summary:

1. Download and install virtualbox
2. Download and install genymotion
3. Download the genymotion ova from the links on [this page](http://echo.com.ng/2014/genymotion-ova-file-download-links/)
4. Copy the downloaded genymotion ova to

   ```
   C:\Users\%User%\AppData\Local\Genymobile\Genymotion\deployed
   ```
5. Enjoy your software

If you experience any issues, please you can use [this workaround](http://echo.com.ng/2014/download-use-genymotion-without-registration/)

Comment: The asker just wanted links though